# Get the user groups in asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get all the groups for a specific user. I can use the below code in .net 4.6.1. It gives me groups for passed user.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
namespace ADAuthentication.AD
{
    public class ADHelper
    {
        public IList<GroupPrincipal> GetUserGroups(string userName)
        {
            var allGroupsOftheUser = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var ADgroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

                foreach (GroupPrincipal groupName in ADgroups)
                {
                    allGroupsOftheUser.Add(groupName);
                }
            }

            return allGroupsOftheUser;
        }
    }
}
```

But in Asp.Net 5 it says,

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    ADAuthentication.DNX Core 5.0
```

My project has following project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```